# asp.net - count how many checkbox is checked then store to variable

Tags: asp.net, session, checkbox

I have my checkboxes

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkSerial" value="serial">Serial
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkProperty" value="property">Property
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkAccountable" value="accountable">Accountable
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkStatus" value="status">Status
```

and im sending it to a `session` variable

```
   Session["checkSerial"] = Request.Form["checkSerial"];
   Session["checkProperty"] = Request.Form["checkProperty"];
   Session["checkAccountable"] = Request.Form["checkAccountable"];
   Session["checkSeries"] = Request.Form["checkSeries"];
```

but im asking is how can I get the count of the checked checkboxes or maybe to count the `Session` I've put. Because I'm doing this in iTextSharp, and the checked will depend the columns like this.

```
if (theCountVariable == 7){
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
}
```

I'm not fond of JS so there is a C# solution I will be really happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If checkbox is not checked, `Request.Form["checkboxname"]` will be null.

```
int theCountVariable = 0;
if (Request.Form["checkSerial"] != null) theCountVariable++;
if (Request.Form["checkProperty"] != null) theCountVariable++;
if (Request.Form["checkAccountable"] != null) theCountVariable++;
if (Request.Form["checkSeries"] != null) theCountVariable++;
```